# Custom Meta Box (SELECT2) Not Saving Taxonomy Terms

Tags: categories, metabox, save-post, wp-update-post

I have the code, 
[image]

```
/*
 * Add a metabox
 * I hope you're familiar with add_meta_box() function, so, nothing new for you here
 */
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'rudr_metabox_for_select2_cat' );
function rudr_metabox_for_select2_cat() {
    add_meta_box( 'rudr_select2', 'Tune Category', 'rudr_display_select2_cat_metabox', 'post', 'side', 'high' );
}
/*
 * Display the fields inside it
 */
function rudr_display_select2_cat_metabox( $post_object ) {
    // I decided to write all the metabox html into a variable and then echo it at the end
    $html = '';

    // always array because we have added [] to our <select> name attribute
    $appended_cat = get_post_meta( $post_object->ID, 'rudr_select2_cat',true ); 
    /*
     * It will be just a multiple select for tags without AJAX search
     * If no tags found - do not display anything
     * hide_empty=0 means to show tags not attached to any posts
     */
    if( $cats = get_terms( 'category', 'hide_empty=0' ) ) {
        $html .= '<p><select id="rudr_select2_cat" name="rudr_select2_cat[]" single="single" style="width:99%;max-width:25em;">';
        foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
            $selected = ( is_array( $appended_cat ) && in_array( $cat->term_id, $appended_cat ) ) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
            $html .= '<option value="' . $cat->term_id . '"' . $selected . '>' . $cat->name . '</option>';
        }
        $html .= '<select></p>';
    }
    echo $html;
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_mishagetcat', 'rudr_get_cat_ajax_callback' ); // wp_ajax_{action}
function rudr_get_cat_ajax_callback(){

    // we will pass post IDs and titles to this array
    $return = array();

    $cat = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'category','search'=> $_GET['q'],'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,));
        foreach ( $cat as $cat ) {  
            // shorten the title a little
            $title = ( mb_strlen( $cat->name ) > 50 ) ? mb_substr( $cat->name, 0, 49 ) . '...' : $cat->name;
            $return[] = array( $cat->term_id, $title ); // array( Post ID, Post Title )
        }
    echo json_encode( $return );
    die;
}
//auto_save
add_action( 'save_post', 'rudr_save_metaboxdata', 10, 2 );
function rudr_save_metaboxdata( $post_id, $post ) {

    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;

    // if post type is different from our selected one, do nothing
    if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        if( isset( $_POST['rudr_select2_cat'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_cat', $_POST['rudr_select2_cat'] );
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_cat' );
        if( isset( $_POST['rudr_select2_tags'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_tags', $_POST['rudr_select2_tags'] );
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_tags' );
    }
    return $post_id;
}
//add_script_&_stylesheet
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'rudr_select2_enqueue' );
function rudr_select2_enqueue(){

    wp_enqueue_style('select2', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script('select2', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js', array('jquery') );

    // please create also an empty JS file in your theme directory and include it too
    wp_enqueue_script('mycustom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/mycustom.js', array( 'jquery', 'select2' ) ); 

}
```

[image]
But Showing only deafult category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you saved the the terms value in a post meta table and not following the wordpress conventional method.

To make it connect with default category with that post you need to modify your `save_post` action. Check the modified code.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'rudr_save_metaboxdata', 10, 2 );
function rudr_save_metaboxdata( $post_id, $post ) {

    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;

    // if post type is different from our selected one, do nothing
    if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        if( isset( $_POST['rudr_select2_cat'] ) )
        {
            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $_POST['rudr_select2_cat', 'category', false) ;
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_cat', $_POST['rudr_select2_cat'] );
        }
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_cat' );
        if( isset( $_POST['rudr_select2_tags'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_tags', $_POST['rudr_select2_tags'] );
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_tags' );
    }
    return $post_id;
}
```

Please check [wp_set_object_terms()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) for reference.

Comment: But giving me wrong category. image- https://imgur.com/gallery/iQbw103

Comment: Then you can pass the slug in your select box option value instead of term id. That will resolved the problem.

Comment: Please Help me again, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/355474/custom-meta-box-select2-giving-wrong-taxonomy-tag

Comment: Same approach for the post tag also. You must pass term slug there. Please accept first answer if you find it working.

Comment: How can i pass the term slug. I will try this code: $tag = get_terms( array('taxonomy' => 'post_tag', 'search'=> $_GET['q'], 'field'    => 'slug', 'terms' => $tag->slug));    code image : https://prnt.sc/qhy01l

Comment: You need to pass term slug instead of term id where you generate tag select options under metabox callback function.

Comment: many many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your Tune Category as deafult category, you have to use `wp_set_post_terms()` with `update_post_meta()`.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'rudr_save_metaboxdata', 10, 2 );
function rudr_save_metaboxdata( $post_id, $post ) {

    if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return $post_id;

    // if post type is different from our selected one, do nothing
    if ( $post->post_type == 'post' ) {
        if( isset( $_POST['rudr_select2_cat'] ) )
        {
             update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_cat', $_POST['rudr_select2_cat'] );
             wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $_POST['rudr_select2_cat'], 'category', FALSE);
        }
        else
        {
           delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_cat' );
           wp_set_post_terms($post_id,'', 'category', FALSE);
        }

        if( isset( $_POST['rudr_select2_tags'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_tags', $_POST['rudr_select2_tags'] );
        else
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'rudr_select2_tags' );
    }
    return $post_id;
}
```

I have tested and it is working fine: https://prnt.sc/qhubbd , https://prnt.sc/qhubjw , https://prnt.sc/qhubf2 , https://prnt.sc/qhubha